# how to update the record with batch in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

the table named: `products`. it have five hundred rows record. the table have field :`products_model`  `products_price`. the `products_model` is unique。

the original value that stored in `products` table are all `0.0000`. now i want to update   it with batch  in phpmyadmin according to the 'products_model`.

i prepared the data in `excel` with two columns, 'products_model`the new value`products_price`(according to some reason, some may be empty). how do i do? thank you.

the data form a csv file :

```
products_model  products_price
LB2100  
LB2117  12.49
LB2381  35.99
LB2307  12.99
LB2380  35.99
LB2468  10.99
LB2139  
LB2223  
LB2027  15.99
LB2126  12.99
LB2308  9.99
LB2124  13.99
LB2077  
LB2361  
LB2021  14.99
LB2129  
LB2010  11.21
LB2186  
LB2039  15.66
LB2153  
LB2564  30.99
LB2104  
LB1182  15.99
LB2034  15.9
LB2455  15.55
LB2189  
LB2559  22.9
LB2382  35.99
LB2168  10.99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Store excel file as CSV (Excel allows it).
2. Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement with REPLACE keyword to update your table.

**Edit:**

About the REPLACE keyword -
From the reference - *If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row.*

The usage is the same -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name' REPLACE INTO TABLE tbl_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY...
```

---

**Code**

Create and populate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
  products_model VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  products_price DECIMAL(5, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (products_model)
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES 
  ('LB2307', 100.00),
  ('LB2380', 200.00),
  ('LB2468', 300.00);
```

Let's import data from CSV:
*Specify FIELDS TERMINATED, LINES TERMINATED and other paramaters for your task*

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE products
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(products_model, @var1)
SET products_price = IF(@var1 = '', 0, @var1); -- Replace empty string with 0
```

Check results:

```
SELECT * FROM products;
+----------------+----------------+
| products_model | products_price |
+----------------+----------------+
| LB1182         |          15.99 |
| LB2010         |          11.21 |
| LB2021         |          14.99 |
| LB2027         |          15.99 |
| LB2034         |          15.90 |
| LB2039         |          15.66 |
| LB2077         |           0.00 |
| LB2100         |           0.00 |
| LB2104         |           0.00 |
| LB2117         |          12.49 |
| LB2124         |          13.99 |
| LB2126         |          12.99 |
| LB2129         |           0.00 |
| LB2139         |           0.00 |
| LB2153         |           0.00 |
| LB2168         |          10.99 |
| LB2186         |           0.00 |
| LB2189         |           0.00 |
| LB2223         |           0.00 |
| LB2307         |          12.99 |
| LB2308         |           9.99 |
| LB2361         |           0.00 |
| LB2380         |          35.99 |
| LB2381         |          35.99 |
| LB2382         |          35.99 |
| LB2455         |          15.55 |
| LB2468         |          10.99 |
| LB2559         |          22.90 |
| LB2564         |          30.99 |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: i am sorry i don't know how to use LOAD DATA INFILE statement with REPLACE keyword t

Comment: i am sorry,i still don't know how to load the csv file. could i put your command in phpmyadmin. eg: the csv named product.csv. how do i do? thank u

Comment: Please add some lines from the CSV file into your question.

Comment: i put a csv file on my question.my site data was divided into  some csv files. could i import them one after another.

Comment: If you have some CSV files you could concatenate these files with a 'cat' *nix command (or maybe with 'copy' command in Windows). Find more information in the internet.

Comment: if products_price is empty。  i will use 0 to fill. i don't where to use your command

Comment: many thanks. there are some part i still don't know. why FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  ', 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'. where shoud i put file_name.csv this file in

Comment: You should specify column and line delimiters; for example in your example field delimiter is '  '; line separator usually is '\r\n' or '\n'. Specify all this in LOAD statement.

Comment: got it, but in the data, the  field delimiter is a space, eg:LB2117  12.49  not ' ', why? where shoud i put file_name.csv file in

Comment: i am sorry, the code doesn't work well, it inserts new rows, not update the old rows.

Comment: Specify YOUR file name, specify YOUR delimiter (in your example it is '  '). The update has to work, the rows are updated by unique products_model. I have never had problems with LOAD DATA INFILE. Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: One more, you also can append/update records from the CSV file with a Data Import tool in dbForge Studio for MySQL. The CSV format has no limitations in free Express Edition - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html

Comment: Did you managed to update records? If no, try to play with it; create a small table with unique ID, populate the table, and load data from test CSV file.

Comment: i tested your code in a test database,it worked ok, but in my products table, the products_model isn't the primary key, the primary is the products_id. but each product only has one products_model.

Comment: I'm note sure if this will help; but make products_model as unique field (add unikue key), load data, then check result, ...and remove created key;-)